# Is it possible to override a designated initializer with a convenience initializer?

Tags: ios

Some one wants to override `UITableViewController`'s designated initializer `- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style`. He added the following code:

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [self init];

    return self;
}
```

and gets 2 warnings :

1. Designated initializer should only invoke a designated initializer on 'super'
2. Designated initializer missing a 'super' call to a designated initializer of the super class

It might be a bad practice to do so. However, is it possible at all to override a designated initializer with a convenience initializer without raising warnings?

Thanks!

Comment: What's in the `init` method?

Comment: @trojanfoe It actually calls [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]... I know it's bad and told him not to do this, but I'm just curious if it is possible at all:)

Comment: Well it seems like the actual code is OK as it does eventually call the super class designated initializer; so it might just be a case of suppressing the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but there are several conditions that must be met in order to get no compiler warnings. ALL designated initialisers for the sub-class must be overridden, also use the **NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER** macro to mark what **init..** methods are to be treated as designated initialisers.

The following is for a sub-class of **UITableViewController** -

**.h**

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style;// this is no longer a designated initialiser

- (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

**.m**

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
//.. no longer treated as designated initialiser
self = [self init];

return self;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]) {
        //.. this is now treated as designated initialiser
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        //.. must implement
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        //.. must implement
    }
    return self;
}
```

Additional info is found in [Adopting Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW9) under Object Initialization.